# How to get the target branch of the GitHub pull request from an Actions?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

When an action is set on `pull_request` in Github Actions, how to get the target branch? The use case is to retrieve the PR- (and hopefully, branch)-specific commits.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can access the target branch with `${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}`.

To know the full list of properties of the `github.event` object, try to run `more $GITHUB_EVENT_PATH`.

Comment: The advantage of this approach compared to Bartleby's answer (currently the most upvoted) is that it also works with `pull_request_review` and `pull_request_review_comment` events. Thanks!

Answer (score 59):

1. When you need the data in expressions ([Source](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context)):

| Property name | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `github.base_ref` | string | The `base_ref` or target branch of the pull request in a workflow run. This property is only available when the event that triggers a workflow run is a `pull_request`. |
| `github.head_ref` | string | The `head_ref` or source branch of the pull request in a workflow run. This property is only available when the event that triggers a workflow run is a `pull_request`. |

An example (modified from [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#example-expression-in-an-if-conditional)):

```yaml
steps:
  - uses: actions/hello-world-javascript-action@v1.1
    if: ${{ github.base_ref == 'main' }}
```

---

2. When you need the data as environment variables ([Source](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables)):

| Environment variable | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `GITHUB_HEAD_REF` | Only set for pull request events. The name of the head branch. |
| `GITHUB_BASE_REF` | Only set for pull request events. The name of the base branch. |

An example (modified from [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables#about-environment-variables)):

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Hello world
    run: echo Hello world from $GITHUB_BASE_REF!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see all GitHub actions pull request event properties [here](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/event-payloads/#pull_request).