# Compare build artifacts from two different commits via github actions

Tags: github-actions, cicd, artifact

I've got a workflow in github actions that automatically creates build artifacts and updates a single release with these new build artifacts every time I merge a PR into `main` ([here's](https://github.com/beyarkay/eskom-calendar) the repo).

I want to know if a new PR will cause a change in the build artifacts (specifically, there's just one CSV file that I care about). Sometimes these changes will be intentional, sometimes not, so I want something like a `git diff` between the CSV file before the PR and the CSV file after the PR.

I know I could setup a github action to:

1. checkout the old version of the code.
2. Run the code to generate the build artifacts
3. save the files of interest to disc
4. checkout the proposed version of the code from the PR
5. Run the PR code to generate the build artifacts
6. `git diff` the version before the PR to the version after the PR.
7. Format and write the `git diff` output as a comment to the PR, letting
   me know about what changes there were so I can check that everything's ok manually.

But this seems like a really common problem and I can't believe there's not a simple
tool/solution out there already? Maybe some github action where you give it two SHAs, a command to run, and a list of files to `git diff`.

To be clear, these are build artifacts, so aren't tracked by git, and so solutions like [`git diff pullrequest main -- myfile.csv`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099742/how-to-compare-files-from-two-different-branches)  won't work.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. A side thought: running the code on `main` (or whatever branch your PR points to) to generate the artifacts and then on the HEAD of the branch isn't DRY. So one approach could be to use `git notes` to keep track of the list of artifacts and their respective SHAs, ready for the next PR.

Comment: TIL about git notes. But wrt the question, I ended up abandoning the attempt because I couldn't find an easy way around it and didn't want to sink a lot of time into the project.

Comment: Well, I had a bit of spare time (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that leverages [`git notes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes):

[image]

(In a nutshell, `git notes` allow you to CRUD metadata to a commit *without touching the commit itself* — and thus preserving history. Cf. § References below.)

Essentially, we want our workflow to:

1. **Build the artefacts**
   We emulate this by running `make build` — to be adapted to your own scenario. For the sake of the example, we also assume that the `build/` directory contains all and only the artefacts generated.
2. **“Remember” the artefacts and their content** (a so-called *“artefacts summary”*)
   We use the `sha512sum` shell command to create a mapping of artefacts' content (represented through their SHA sum) to their file name.
   We retrieve all artefacts via `find results/ -type f`, and then convert the mapping to a CSV with headers using `sed 's/  /,/' | cat <(echo 'sha512,file_name') -`
3. **Attach the *artefacts summary* to the commit**
   That's where we leverage `git notes`, which allows us to add metadata to the commit ex-post, without modifying the history.

These steps should be executed for any commit on your main branch.

In case of a PR, you also want to repeat these steps on the branch's `HEAD`, plus:

4. **Retrieve the *artefacts summary* of your PR's target branch**
   So you now have two artefacts summaries to compare: base (your `main`/`master` branch's one) and head (the branch of your PR). In the example below, the *base* is hard coded to `main`, but you could refine this by [letting the workflow retrieve the target branch's name automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62331829/5433628).
5. **Compare both artefacts summaries**
   I've created the [`artefactscomparison` Python package](https://pypi.org/project/artefactscomparison/) for that purpose. (Note: it's very much tailored to my use case and desiderata.)
6. **Add the artefact comparison report to your PR**
   Beebop, a bot will do that for you.

In the end, you should see something like on the screenshot above.

```yaml
name: Artefacts Comparison

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

  pull_request:
    branches:

permissions: write-all

jobs:
  build_artefacts:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: ${{ github.token }}
      - name: Build artefacts
        run: make build
      - name: Generate artefacts summary
        id: artefacts-summary
        run: |
          echo "ARTEFACTS_SUMMARY<<EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          find build/ -type f -exec sha512sum {} \; | sed 's/  /,/' | cat <(echo 'sha512,file_name') - >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Add the artefacts summary as a git notes
        run: |
          git fetch origin refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
          git config user.name "github-actions"
          git config user.email "bot@github.com"
          git notes add -m "${{ steps.artefacts-summary.outputs.ARTEFACTS_SUMMARY }}"
          git notes show
          git push origin refs/notes/*
  # In case of PR, add report of artefacts comparison
  compare_artefacts:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: ${{ github.token }}
      - name: Pull artefacts summaries (i.e., git notes) from upstream
        run: |
          git fetch origin refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
      - name: Retrieve PR's head branch's artefacts summary
        id: artefact-summary-head
        run: |
          echo "ARTEFACTS_SUMMARY<<EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          git notes show >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Retrieve PR's target branch's artefacts summary
        id: artefact-summary-base
        run: |
          git checkout ${{ github.base_ref }}
          echo "ARTEFACTS_SUMMARY<<EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          git notes show >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"
      - name: Install artefactscomparison package
        run: pip install -U artefactscomparison
      - name: Generate artefact comparison report
        id: artefact-comparison-report
        run: |
          echo "${{ steps.artefact-summary-head.outputs.ARTEFACTS_SUMMARY }}" > head.csv
          echo "${{ steps.artefact-summary-base.outputs.ARTEFACTS_SUMMARY }}" > base.csv
          echo "ARTEFACTS_REPORT<<EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          artefacts_comparison -b base.csv -h head.csv >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Comment PR with artefact comparison report
        uses: thollander/actions-comment-pull-request@v2
        with:
          message: ${{ steps.artefact-comparison-report.outputs.ARTEFACTS_REPORT }}
          comment_tag: artefact_comparison_report
          mode: recreate
    needs: build_artefacts
```

---

<sub>**References:**</sub>

- <sub>[`git notes` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes)</sub>
- <sub>[How to sync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269026/5433628) (i.e. “pull” and push) `git notes` with upstream</sub>
- <sub>[git notes | Enhance Git Commit Messages with Notes](https://initialcommit.com/blog/git-notes)</sub>
- <sub>[Git Notes: git's coolest, most unloved­ feature](https://tylercipriani.com/blog/2022/11/19/git-notes-gits-coolest-most-unloved-feature/)</sub>
- <sub>[Automatically add `git notes` via Github Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75232159/5433628)</sub>

Comment: You're an amazing human.